# c++ draw line with SDL

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I am making a program to simplify using SDL and I don't know how I could draw a line without using trigonometry. I would like it to be able to have a thickness setting as well.

Here is some of the code:

```
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const Uint32 fps = 60; //Set speed in fps (frames per second)
const Uint32 minframetime = 1000 / fps;

class SDL_helper
{
public:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    Uint32 frametime;
    bool running = true;

    void start() {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); //Display window
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC); //Create renderer

        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, 1);
        SDL_SetWindowResizable(window, SDL_TRUE);
    }

    void updateLoop() {
        while (running) {
            update();
        }
    }

    void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int t, int r, int g, int b, int a) {
        
    }

    void render() {
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    void correctFramerate() {
        if (SDL_GetTicks() - frametime < minframetime) { //Check if it is running at the right speed
            SDL_Delay(minframetime - (SDL_GetTicks() - frametime));
        }
    }

    void update();
    
};
```

Comment: Have a look at the SDL reference. It looks like `SDL_RenderDrawLine` takes your start and end points as you provide, and you'll want to call `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` to set the colour. http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawLine?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like thickness isn't a standard parameter in SDL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24305966/2148605

Comment: You can see here how SDL2_gfx implements thick line drawing (Line 4115). It's quite a lot of work, so I would suggest just using SDL2_gfx instead if at all possible. https://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL2_gfx/Docs/html/_s_d_l2__gfx_primitives_8c_source.html#l04115